# How to use a relay in Python graphql-core

Tags: python, graphql

The following code produces a `TypeError` error

`TypeError: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named 'Query'.`

```py
import json
from graphql.utilities import build_schema
from graphql.type import GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema

def read_file(file_path, is_json: bool = False):
    file_contents = None
    try:
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            file_contents = file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File '{file_path}' not found.")
    except IOError:
        print(f"Error reading file '{file_path}'.")

    if not file_contents:
        raise Exception("GraphQL schema is empty")

    return json.loads(file_contents) if is_json else file_contents


schema = build_schema(read_file("schemas/github.graphql"))

GraphQLSchema(GraphQLObjectType('Query', lambda:schema.query_type.fields))
```

[Github's GraphQL public schema](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/public-schema) includes a relay Query type as follows:

```
type Query {
  ...

  """
  Workaround for re-exposing the root query object. (Refer to
  https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/112 for more information.)
  """
  relay: Query!
 ...

}
```

When using this schema in [graphql-core](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core) python library I get a type error if I try to rebuild the schema.

`TypeError: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named 'Query'.`

Is that a bug in `graphql-core` code or am I missing something? How to properly handle relays like that?